# how to write NSURLSession singletone class in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsurlsession

I am new to IOS(Objective C). just started with iPhone App using NSURLSession which will communicate with server after authentication.

We have WEB Apis and i have to authorize iPhone app with server by providing Username/Password.

I do not know how to start with whether to use sharedSession or sessionWithConfiguration.

i tried below code for singleton but its not perfect :

```
- (NSURLSession *)createSession
{
    static NSURLSession *session = nil;
    session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]
                                            delegate:self
                                       delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
    return session;
}
```

then **where should i use**

```
sessionConfiguration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{
                                               @"api-key"       : @"API_KEY",
                                               @"Content-Type"  : @"application/json"
                                               };
```

**and how to pass receive token back to server ?**

Comment: If you write this NSURLSession by yourself then you have to consider scenarios like BackgroundThread, Mainqueue, background queue etc., Try to use the Famous libraries like AFNetworking etc., Library will handle the lot of scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

to write singleton :

```
+(InstanceType)shareInstance{
static dispatch_One_t onceToken;
static NSURLSession * session;

dispatch_one(&onceToken,^{

session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]
                                            delegate:self
                                       delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
});
 return session;

}
```

but to your question :
and how to pass receive token back to server ?

you should use block .

Comment: what is block , can you please send me sample code...as i tried to used HTTPAdditionalHeaders but i am not getting any data....

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

but to call the above code

[NSURLSession shareInstance];